# Output cells aren't working correctly in a .ipynb VSCode notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

The strangest issue has just started cropping up in my python notebooks in VScode. I created a chatbot using the EXACT code from [this ChatGPT tutorial](https://learn.deeplearning.ai/chatgpt-prompt-eng/lesson/8/chatbot).

When I get to the part of the code below I'm greeted by the chatbot, but when I type my responses anytime I type certain letters it's like I'm activating VSCODE shortcuts. The letter 'a' opens a new cell (and skips the cursor out of the text box). The letter 'o' collapses the output of the cell where the text box is, and 'f' opens the find text window that you normally open with 'command f'. Why are these keystrokes suddenly triggering shortcuts?

When I execute this code in a Jupyter notebook everything works fine. I've also tried the [Keybinding issues trobleshooting page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues#basic-troubleshooting) and nothing close to what I'm experiencing shows up there

```py
button_conversation = pn.widgets.Button(name="Chat!")
interactive_conversation = pn.bind(collect_messages, button_conversation)
pn.extension(scroll=True)
dashboard = pn.Column(
    interactive_conversation,
    inp,
    pn.Row(button_conversation)
)
dashboard
```

Comment: You probably *are* activating VSCode shortcuts. It doesn't seem like a notebook cell is a good place for chatting, really.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.